# Docker Swarm across 2 sites or xCluster in YugabyteDB?

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I am wondering if for the attached (image) setup I should be trying to setup xCluster/Asynchronous Replication between Site A and Site B as described in https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/deploy/multi-dc/async-replication/ or simply create a single swarm of containers across both sites. Is there any reason that xCluster/Async won’t work?

Some notes:
Basically there are two physical sites that connect to a single telco company.

Via dynamic DNS I can get a static url that maps to whatever the variable IP address of the link is at the time.

Internally to each site the machines only natively talk to each other via their internal IP addresses but use the dynamic DNS to communicate with machines at the other site via port forwarding.

The goal at this stage is a yb-master and yb-server on each node.

Perhaps it’s all handled by the magic of Docker networking and Yugabyte works seamlessly with all that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The servers will need to connect to each other directly as they do internally. Think A2 sends/receives changes to B2 directly.